# How to protect subdomain in Apache while developing?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, subdomain

I need to do some maintenance work to my blog, which is under http://blog.ricardoamaral.net and I'm looking for the best way to protect all outside access, but my own, to that subdomain. So I can work peacefully without people seeing what I'm doing.

I thought uf using an .htaccess file and deny every one access but my own IP but this presents a problem. I'm on a dynamic IP ISP and I would be needing to keep changing my IP on the .htaccess file, which is a pain.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would password protection work for you? Add this to the .htaccess file

```
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Secret Folder"
Require valid-user
```

Then to add users to the password file:

```
htpasswd -c /full/path/to/.htpasswd fred
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a password on that part of the site.  Use simple http authentication through Apache.  Any application behind it, unless it also uses http authentication, will just do its own thing.